# Баг с графикой Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, 3d, текстура

Когда я создаю объект, он начинает переливаться розовым и зеленым (в зависимости от света)
Из-за этой проблемы невидно текстуры наложенные на объект. В скомпелированном виде тот-же хрен.
Версия: 2018.1.9f2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас в консоли ошибка отображается.

Comment: `This is due to a change in the default lightmapping resolution for scenes made with the lightweight 3d template. Until this is addressed, you can fix this by increasing the lightmap resolution found in the Lighting window to 40. ` - Karl.
Попробуйте увеличить разрешение lightmap в окне "Освещение".

Comment: Не помогло(((((

Comment: материал на кубе какой стоит?

Comment: Необходимо увидеть инспектор на кубе.